# Is there a recommended way to plot data using ascii symbols?

Tags: c, plot, ascii

I am writing a bare-metal C language test program that captures some sensor data, analyzes and plots it. The data is pretty simple and I only have a serial console interface. Still, I would like to plot the waveform using only mono-spaced ascii characters.

Is there a standard, recommended way to do something like this?

```
256  |           *
     |          *
     |            *
     |         *   *
128  |        *     *
     |       *       *       *  
     |   *                 ** *
     | ** ***         * * *    **
  0  _______________________________
```

Comment: Did you post almost the exact same question about an hour or so ago? Don't repost questions, improve the one you have.

Comment: And please take some more time to read or refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. Also read about [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Oh and some unrelated nitpicking: ASCII is a way to encode characters, and has nothing to do with monospacing or other glyph or font related things. It's up to the receiver to display it in a suitable font for it to make sense, it's nothing you can enforce in your program.

Comment: @Some programmer dude, Except "ASCII art" is a thing, and that the usage being used here. (I'll grant you the OP's wording is awkward.)

Comment: @ikegami It might be called ASCII art, but it's still not related to monospacing glyphs or fonts. If the viewer is, for some weird reason, not using a monospaced glyph set (font) in their terminal, neither this output nor "ASCII art" will display properly. Like I said, it's noting the author of the art, or the OP in her or his program, can controll.

Comment: @Some programmer dude, Re "*it's still not related to monospacing glyphs or fonts*", Nonsense. ASCII art requires monospace font. And so does the OP's graph. Just like they said.

Comment: @Pedro_Uno "Is there a standard ... way to do something like this?" --> No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply a pair of nested loops.

```c
size_t n = 26;

for ( size_t y = 8; y--; ) {
   int miny = ( y + 0 ) * 8;
   int maxy = ( y + 1 ) * 8;

   for ( size_t x = 0; x < n; ++x ) {
      putchar( miny <= samples[ x ] && samples[ x ] < maxy ? '*' : ' ' );
   }

   putchar( '\n' );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could open a pipe to [`gnuplot`](http://www.gnuplot.vt.edu/), if available.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *gnu = popen("gnuplot", "w");
    if(!gnu) { perror("gnuplot"); return EXIT_FAILURE; }
    fprintf(gnu, "set term dumb\n"
        "$Data <<EOD\n"
        "10\n10\n70\n10\n10\n10\n"
        "100\n130\n160\n230\n260\n200\n"
        "160\n130\n100\n10\n10\n10\n60\n"
        "70\n80\n60\n20\n10\nEOD\n"
        "plot $Data\n");
    pclose(gnu);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Gives me,

```
  300 +--------------------------------------------------------------------+   
      |             +             +            +             +             |   
      |                                                      $Data    A    |   
  250 |-+                         A                                      +-|   
      |                                                                    |   
      |                        A                                           |   
      |                                                                    |   
  200 |-+                           A                                    +-|   
      |                                                                    |   
      |                     A          A                                   |   
  150 |-+                                                                +-|   
      |                  A                A                                |   
      |                                                                    |   
  100 |-+              A                     A                           +-|   
      |                                                                    |   
      |     A                                             A  A             |   
      |                                                 A       A          |   
   50 |-+                                                                +-|   
      |                                                                    |   
      |  A    A  A  A             +            A  A  A       +     A A     |   
    0 +--------------------------------------------------------------------+   
      0             5             10           15            20            25
```

You haven't really supplied the details of the capabilities of the terminal you are using. For example, you, or someone with access, may need to download the `gnuplot` package from your package manager.

Comment: Neil, gnuplot is a very good idea. I was not aware it supported dumb terminals.  Unfortunately, my application is bare-metal. By that I mean there is no OS.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Ikegami's suggestion adapted to my environment.

```
void plot_samples(uint8_t *data, int n)
{
    const int n_rows = 32;
    const int max_val = 256;
    const int row_span = max_val/n_rows;

    xil_printf("%3d | ", max_val);
    for (int col=0; col<n; col++) xil_printf("-");
    xil_printf("|\n\r");
    int row_min_val;
    for (int row=n_rows-1; row>=0; row--){
        row_min_val = row*row_span;
        xil_printf("%3d | ", row_min_val);
        for (int col=0; col<n; col++){
            if (data[col] >= row_min_val) {
                xil_printf("*");
            } else {
                xil_printf(" ");
            }
        }
        xil_printf("|\n\r");
    }
    xil_printf("\n\r");
}
```

[image]